# adding text boxes to a photoshop template using dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I used photoshop to make a template and also used the slice tool to make buttons. I am trying to add a couple of boxes on my template so people can out the info (name,email,massage) and send it to my email. When i click insert > form > text field it adds a box but at the bottom of my page, not on my template. Is there anyway i can get the text field box on my template?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Home page.png) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="823" height="885" border="0" cellpadding="0"     cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
        <img src="images/Home-page_01.jpg" width="823" height="127" alt="">             </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="images/Home-page_02.jpg" alt="" width="99" height="30" border="0" usemap="#Map"></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/Home-page_03.jpg" alt="" width="155" height="30" border="0" usemap="#Map2"></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/Home-page_04.jpg" alt="" width="98" height="30" border="0" usemap="#Map3"></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/Home-page_05.jpg" alt="" width="193" height="30" border="0" usemap="#Map4"></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/Home-page_06.jpg" width="278" height="30" alt="">     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5"><!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="EditRegion1" --><img   src="images/Home-page_07.jpg" alt="" width="823" height="728" border="0" usemap="#Map5">
      <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    </form>
    <!-- TemplateEndEditable --></td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->

<map name="Map">
<area shape="rect" coords="1,3,99,28" href="#">
</map>

<map name="Map2">
<area shape="rect" coords="7,2,158,30" href="#">
</map>

<map name="Map3">
<area shape="rect" coords="3,4,95,30" href="#">
</map>

<map name="Map4">
<area shape="rect" coords="11,2,189,33" href="#">
</map>

<map name="Map5">
<area shape="rect" coords="267,247,486,356" href="#">
<area shape="rect" coords="9,248,250,356" href="#">
<area shape="rect" coords="519,246,763,354" href="#">
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

u can just focus the cursor on where you want add text field and repeat your step, it will put text field where you focus the cursor...